# jquery methods are not firing with css class names after moving to js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

below methods are working fine when I have them in razor or partial views. after them to JS from these are not at all. JS file is loading and other regular javascript methods working fine. What could be the wrong?

```
    $('.phonelocation').on('change', function () {
    $("#HdnCommunicationLocation").val(this.value); // or $(this).val()
});
$('.phonetype').on('change', function () {
    $("#HdnCommunicationType").val(this.value); // or $(this).val()
 $('.phoneCountry').trigger('change');
});
$('.phoneCountry').change(function () {
..
}
```

Comment: will these js are added on **document.ready** method ?

Comment: What are you using to compile the js files if you're not using razor?

Comment: try tying it to the document $(document).on('change', '.phonelocation', function(){...

Comment: how come $(document).on('change', '.phonetype', working? what is the difference?

Comment: didn't get flagged you had made a comment so just saw this.  Nayish's explanation below is correct.  The element doesn't exist on page load so tying the event to the document and adding a selector for the element will fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the js after the document is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', '.phonelocation', function () {
        $("#HdnCommunicationLocation").val(this.value); // or $(this).val()
    });
    $(document).on('change', '.phonetype', function () {
        $("#HdnCommunicationType").val(this.value); // or $(this).val()
        $('.phoneCountry').trigger('change');
    });
    $(document).on('change', '.phoneCountry', function () {
        ..
    }
});
```

**update:** try adding the events to the document that way no matter when the elwments are added the events will still work

Comment: as of my knowledge js file can have multiple `$(document).ready(function ()` correct?

Comment: it didn't working! those class names are not defined in css files but on control I defined.

Comment: how come `$(document).on('change', '.phonetype',` working? what is the difference?

Comment: The event is added to the document and not the element which I guess doesnt exist at the time the document loads